# Implicit DLL linking and class-internal functions

Tags: c++, dll, linker

I'm experimenting with writing a wrapper class for SQLite to be exposed through a DLL using implicit linking, i.e. producing library and header files for consumers to compile and link against.

At the moment I'm exporting the wrapper class, but when I attempt to compile the project that consumes this wrapper class I'm getting linker errors about not being able to resolve the sqlite API calls, e.g. sqlite3_open.  Both the wrapper class and the consumer are C++, but sqlite is C.

Why does the consumer need to know about functions that are not exposed to it (the whole point of the wrapper class)?  Does this mean I need to modify the SQLite header to change its functions to have the appropriate _declspec(dllexport) decoration for all functions/the functions I'm wrapping?  Are there alternatives to this change?

The linker errors:

```
libsqlite.lib(sqlitewrapper.oxl) : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol _sq
lite3_close referenced in function "public: virtual __thiscall CSQLiteWrapper::~
CSQLiteWrapper(void)" (??1CSQLiteWrapper@@UAE@XZ)

libsqlite.lib(sqlitewrapper.oxl) : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol _sq
lite3_open referenced in function "public: __thiscall CSQLiteWrapper::CSQLiteWra
pper(class ATL::CStringT<char,class ATL::StrTraitATL<char,class ATL::ChTraitsCRT
<char> > > const &)" (??0CSQLiteWrapper@@QAE@ABV?$CStringT@DV?$StrTraitATL@DV?$C
hTraitsCRT@D@ATL@@@ATL@@@ATL@@@Z)

libsqlite.lib(sqlitewrapper.oxl) : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol _sq
lite3_free referenced in function "public: virtual void __thiscall CSQLiteWrappe
r::Exec(class ATL::CStringT<char,class ATL::StrTraitATL<char,class ATL::ChTraits
CRT<char> > > const &,int (__cdecl*)(void *,int,char * *,char * *))" (?Exec@CSQL
iteWrapper@@UAEXABV?$CStringT@DV?$StrTraitATL@DV?$ChTraitsCRT@D@ATL@@@ATL@@@ATL@
@P6AHPAXHPAPAD2@Z@Z)

libsqlite.lib(sqlitewrapper.oxl) : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol _sq
lite3_exec referenced in function "public: virtual void __thiscall CSQLiteWrappe
r::Exec(class ATL::CStringT<char,class ATL::StrTraitATL<char,class ATL::ChTraits
CRT<char> > > const &,int (__cdecl*)(void *,int,char * *,char * *))" (?Exec@CSQL
iteWrapper@@UAEXABV?$CStringT@DV?$StrTraitATL@DV?$ChTraitsCRT@D@ATL@@@ATL@@@ATL@
@P6AHPAXHPAPAD2@Z@Z)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The root cause of my issue was that I was using the "lib" command to generate the library I was then linking against.  As Ixop mentions, in that case I would need to make sure SQLite is getting added to my library even though it wasn't directly exposed in the DLL.

However with implicit linking, what I should have been doing was using the [IMPLIB](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/67wc07b9%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) linker directive to generate the library instead.  Making this change to how I was building it fixed the issue.

Answer (score 2):

Have you statically linked your wrapper against the SQLite libraries?  Doing that should mean that everything lives within your library, rather than it just being a gateway, so the linker errors should go away.  That's assuming you're not wanting to keep the SQLite library separate from your wrapper of course.

Comment: +1, this would have been a solution but not the one that I was looking for, as it wouldn't have been the implicit linking solution.